# What js template engine is that?

Tags: javascript, node.js, template-engine

I'm working in huge nodejs project. It comes from outsource guys. It contains hundreds of plugins and libraries. I can't recognize a template engine which uses in it. Can someboby help with this? 
Samples:

```
    var $mapsIfAlbum = (
      <section class="slide section" data-index="2" style={{top: mapsPos + '%', zIndex: mapsPos}}>
        <div class="maps">
          {info}
          <_Maps />
        </div>
      </section>
    );
```

This one looks like Mustache, but both pieces are in one file. Is it posible to use two template engines in one file?

```
var bodyStyles = `
${hideIconsWhenMobile}
  @media screen and (max-width: 720px) {
    body {
      background: #fff !important;
    }
  }
  `;
```

Comment: which template engine you want to use ?

Comment: I see backticks I think its [Template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first looks like it's JSX which is commonly used with [React](https://facebook.github.io/react/).

And yes like others have mentioned, the second one is a template literal.

Comment: Yes, I know this already) I get answer in another question, but thanks for this archeology.

Answer (score 1):

It is called as **Template Literals**.

When you update your **NodeJS** to version **4.0.0** and above, This is considered to be a new feature from **ES6** where you can use this `backquotes`, (also known as `grave accents`) instead of using `+` for concatenation.

Hope this helps!